# Retrosynthesis suggestion

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

Am I even close to solve this problem or it is a complete disaster?

[image]

Comment: For one thing, to make a diazonium salt with NaNO2/HCl you need an amino group on the aromatic ring. Perhaps only a partial disaster. ;) Oh yes, welcome to ChemSE!

Comment: @Frederico  I think it would help you to look up the reactions of 2-halopyridines with nucleophiles

Comment: Out of curiosity:  The scheme suggests a C-N coupling reaction between 1,8-diazanaphthalene and an aryldiazonium salt.  May someone indicate the name for this type of reaction or / and a literature example for such a transformation?

Comment: Photoarylation of pyridine with an aryl diazonium salt at all positions of pyridine has been reported: DOI:10.1021/acs.joc.9b0187 Can't speak to the suggestion by the OP. @Buttonwood

Comment: @user55119 Perhaps we are not on the same page, do you refer to Bartomoleu, 2019JOC10459 (doi 10.1021/acs.joc.9b01879) -- as the last figure was truncated?  Scheme 2 of the paper and the NMR of the 88 p. SI read like pyridines / quinolines / quinoxalines underwent C-H arylation at 2, or / and 4 position relative to N, but no NMR record evidence of a C-N bond formation with what was a pyridine-N.  But even if there was a misunderstanding here, good to know about this photo mediated approach, since one of rules of retrosynthesis is «the strategy is better if a similar reaction already was seen».

Comment: @Buttonwood: The reference was truncated. Sorry.  I searched pyridine and phenyldiazonium cation as reactants in Chem. Absts. No evidence for what the OP drew in the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible route:
Start from the commercially available 2,6-dichloro-5-fluoropyridine-3-carboxylic acid (**1**). Form the Weinreb amide (**2**) *via* the acid chloride. React this with vinyl magnesium bromide to form (**3**). React the product with 1 eq of aniline in the presence of non-nucleophilic base to produce (**4**). Isolate this product and react with excess piperazine for the final product (**5**).

[image]

Comment: The closest analogue found by ChemSpider is this one : http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.26951527.html?rid=fa825ba9-6765-4789-9e1d-13d6495e6f3b ; I wonder if that keto ester could help with the synthesis and be removed at the end by hydrolysis and decarboxylation.

Comment: Yes, I think the hydrolysis and decarboxylation would deliver the desired structure. The difference would come down to the yields in installing the vinyl ketone v the methylene beta keto-ester

Comment: I was thinking more of installing that C-C moiety the other way around. Suppose you start from an ester of your (1), do the substitution of the 2-Cl with the aniline, then a Michael addition to an acrylate and an intramolecular acylation (Dieckmann?). Just to avoid harsh nucleophylic conditions on such an electrophylic molecule. But yes, your route seems more direct.

Comment: user6376297: The Dieckmann route has been applied in this series of cmpds. T. Miyamoto, H. Egawa and j. Matsumoto, Chem. Pharm. Bull., 1987, 35, 2280.

Comment: This discussion illustrates very clearly that there is rarely only a single potential route to a target

Comment: @user55119 : OK, thanks, good to know! So perhaps leaving the lab for the 'dark side' (chemoinformatics) did not make me forget all my organic chemistry...

Comment: BTW, computers are at it, too: ai3sd.org/aireact2020/abstracts ; postera.ai/demo ; https://askcos.mit.edu/ ...